# Unable to set border properties on position fixed <thead>

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to make a sticky `<thead>` over a multi-`<tbody>` HTML `<table>`.

Problem is that, with reference to this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uxqpajqk/), I'm unable to show any cell border on the `<thead>` with `position: fixed` property.

I'm using Bootstrap's class `table-bordered` that should be cloned in the temporary table, but this is not working. I even tried setting the property specifically for the `#clonedTable th`, but it is not working as well.

The only thing happening is that if for example I set a `border: 10px solid red`, the cloned `<thead>` has a 10px transparent margin (which I suppose is a not correctly rendered margin).

I'm working over a Firefox 53.0.3, but I tested also over a Chrome 58.0.3029.110 with the same result.

Is there any way that I'm missing to show these borders??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update below css part:

```
.table thead tr th {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 2px red inset;
  margin:2px;
}
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rujqjk4x/2/)

```css
    body {
      height: 5000px
    }
    th, td {
      background-color: #fff;
    }
   .table thead tr th {
     box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 2px red inset;
     margin:2px;
   }
```

```html
<table class="table table-condensed table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>col1</th>
      <th>col2</th>
      <th>col3</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>test</td>
      <td>test</td>
      <td>test</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>test</td>
      <td>test</td>
      <td>test</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>test</td>
      <td>test</td>
      <td>test</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>test</td>
      <td>test</td>
      <td>test</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>test</td>
      <td>test</td>
      <td>test</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>test</td>
      <td>test</td>
      <td>test</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>test</td>
      <td>test</td>
      <td>test</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>test</td>
      <td>test</td>
      <td>test</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>test</td>
      <td>test</td>
      <td>test</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<div id="bottomAnchor"></div>
<div id="clonedHolder"></div>
```

Comment: Nope. As written, i've tried this solution already with no success.

Comment: Then you can use box shadow as @ovokuro post the answer

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure why the border won't apply, but you can get the same effect with box-shadow, which does seem to work..

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rujqjk4x/1/)

```js
function moveScroll() {
  var realTable = $('table');
  var lastTobody = realTable.find('tbody:last-child');
  var scroll = $(window).scrollTop() + realTable.find('thead').outerHeight();
  var topLimit = realTable.offset().top;
  var bottomLimit = lastTobody.offset().top + lastTobody.outerHeight();
  if (scroll > topLimit && scroll < bottomLimit) {
    clonedTable = $('#clonedTable');
    if (clonedTable.length == 0) {
      clonedTable = realTable.clone();
      clonedTable.attr('id', 'clonedTable');
      clonedTable.css({
        'width': realTable.width(),
        'visibility': 'hidden',
        'position': 'fixed',
        'pointer-events': 'none',
        'top': 0
      });
      $('#clonedHolder').append(clonedTable);
      $('#clonedTable thead').css({
        visibility: 'visible'
      });
    }
  } else {
    $('#clonedTable').remove();
  }
}

$(window).scroll(moveScroll);
```

```css
body {
  height: 5000px
}

th,
td {
  background-color: #fff;
}

#clonedTable thead tr {
  box-shadow: 0 1px 0 red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<table class="table table-condensed table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>col1</th>
      <th>col2</th>
      <th>col3</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>test</td>
      <td>test</td>
      <td>test</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>test</td>
      <td>test</td>
      <td>test</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>test</td>
      <td>test</td>
      <td>test</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>test</td>
      <td>test</td>
      <td>test</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>test</td>
      <td>test</td>
      <td>test</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>test</td>
      <td>test</td>
      <td>test</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>test</td>
      <td>test</td>
      <td>test</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>test</td>
      <td>test</td>
      <td>test</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>test</td>
      <td>test</td>
      <td>test</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<div id="bottomAnchor"></div>
<div id="clonedHolder"></div>
```

Comment: Interesting. Unfortunately this way i'm losing borders between the cells (which are quite important to preserve).